# Retrieving a document where one of its reference fields fulfill a condition

Tags: python, mongoengine

I am trying to retrieve the id  from the child document based on a condition of one of its fields . Here are the document schemas.

```
class father(DynamicDocument):
    name = StringField

class child(DynamicDocument):
    name = StringField
    parent = ReferenceField('father')
```

How can I get the id of the child where its father's name is 'Anakin'?

I am trying with this query:

```
Child.objects.filter(parent__name=Father.objects(name='Anakin').first().id).first().id
```

But it results to:

```
mongoengine.errors.InvalidQueryError: Cannot perform join in mongoDB: parent__name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this in 1 query as MongoDB has no join.

The recommended way to do this with MongoEngine, is by using 2 queries:

```
anakin = Father.objects(name='Anakin').first()
anakin_childs = Child.objects.filter(parent=anakin) #.first() if you are only interested in first match
```

The [CachedReferenceField](https://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html?highlight=cachedreferencefield#mongoengine.fields.CachedReferenceField) may also be of interest to you, it caches (i.e duplicate) some attributes in the parent collection allowing you to do such "join". But it comes with decreased performance due to the overhead of keeping the cached attribute in sync with the original document.

Comment: I agree. I also tried with two queries, just like you said, but it will not serve the purpose I want it to. I used a work around with embedded document fields and it seems to work better lately, time will show. Thank you!